# Difference between a multivariate normal regression and multiple regressions with shared random effect

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, random-effects-model, correlation-matrix

Let's $Y_1$, $Y_2$ be two random variables representing two outcomes and $X$ a covariate. I want two regress $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$ on X, but by taking into account the potential correlation between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

Here are two models that I considered so far:

**Model 1:**

$Y_{1,j} = \alpha_1 + \gamma_j + \beta X_j + \varepsilon_1$, where $\varepsilon_1\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, and

$Y_{2,j} = \alpha_2 + \gamma_j + \beta X_j + \varepsilon_2$, where $\varepsilon_2\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$,

with $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ independent, $\gamma_j$ a random effect: $\gamma_j \sim N(0,\tau^2)$

**Model 2:**

$Y_j = \alpha + \beta X_j + \varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon \sim N(0,\Sigma)$,

where $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$, $\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2+\tau^2 & \tau^2 \\
\tau^2 & \sigma^2+\tau^2
\end{pmatrix}$

**Question**: Are the two models equivalent?

If yes, what is the proof?

If no, how they differ?

Comment: Are we confident that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are positively correlated?  It's implied in model 2 by the squaring of $\tau$ and is the only case that can be captured in model 1, but just wanted to check...  (Model 2 could, on the other hand, easily be relaxed to model negative correlations, whereas model 1 absolutely cannot).

Comment: That's a good point Phil. I was thinking of an example with positive correlation between Y, yes, but then it would be interesting to see and prove whether model 1 is a particular case of model 2.

Comment: I *think* you've sort of made them equivalent by having just one $\beta$ and positive correlations.  Just looking by eye, they seem to boil down to the same thing.  I'm not expert on multivariate regression, but I would *guess* that your model 2 is, however, a subset of multivariate regression?  Do you have a particular use in mind?  I guess in some cases one shared $\beta$ can make sense and others not?  I don't know how to write and absolutely formal proof, by $\gamma_j + (\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$ is for sure distributed as per $\epsilon$ in model 2, so think they're equivalent.

Comment: (Easy to see that they are distributed that way because covariance of $(\gamma_j, \gamma_j)$ is a 2x2 matrix with $\tau^2$ in every element.)  Also, one afterthought, I think model 1 could be relaxed to handle negative correlations if you had a coeff on $\gamma_j$.

Comment: Yeah it seems easy to see it, but I wanted to see have a proof that shows clearly that from Model 1 we end up to Model 2.

Comment: Proof I think is just to write both equations from model 1 in vector form.  You'll end up adding together two normally distributed random vectors, and we know when we do that, that their covariances sum and bosh you've got model 2.  Main point I was making though was in reference to your title, in that model 2 isn't really (I think) multivariate regression, but rather just a vector format of model 1.

Comment: Technically, it is multivariate regression as there are multiple outcomes.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was just thinking some more.  It is a constrained multivariate regression.  Constrained to capture method 1.  But method 2 is just a restatement of model 1.